# Can you omit the "this" keyword when using function pointer to nonstatic member function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, static, this

I'm delving into the topic of non-static member function pointers, and I find the syntax most disturbing. These pointers are interesting because you can do:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    void nonStaticMembFunc1(){};
    void nonStaticMembFunc2()
    {
         void (MyStruct::*funcPtr)() = &nonStaticMembFunc1;   // Declare local pointer

         (this->*funcPtr)();   // Use it through this instance

    }
};
```

So if it's the case that you can always (as far as I know) drop the use of the "this" keyword, I tried to drop it in this case, with the following attempts:

```
(this->*nonStaticFuncPtr)();    // Normal use, works

(->*function1)();   // Trying to drop "this" keyword            
(*function1)();     // Trying to drop the arrow, this seemed to make sense
(.*function1)();    // Trying the other way
```

Trying this made me confused about what scope you're in when in a nonstatic member function. If you can drop the keyword then you're already in its scope (if that's the right term), like when you can drop the use of the scope resolution :: operator if you don't need it. But I'm probably completely wrong about this.

Comment: Is your question why is there an `this` pointer if one is already automatically in the class scope, so `this` is unnecessary?

Comment: `&nonStaticMembFunc1` is invalid and shouldn't even compile. Pointers to member functions must be fully qualified: `&MyStruct::nonStaticMembFunc1`. BTW `MyStruct`'s declaration misses an ending `;`

Comment: @Rakete No, my question is if you can drop the use of it, like you can normally. You don't need it normally because when entering the function it already has the "this" pointer if I understand right.

Comment: @wasthishelpful Right, but seeing as though you're already in the class's scope, you don't need the MyStruct:: , I think, at least my Visual Studio isn't showing an error.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice [Why not simply try out](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f62e19bc70050ef)? _"you don't need the MyStruct:: ..."_ That's wrong BTW.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I did, it doesn't work. And really, the syntax is that confusing I didn't really expect it to work. But my (bad) logic said that seeing as though the function already has the "this" pointer... I dunno.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice I don't know which version of visual you're using, but visual 2015 shows an error (as it should)

Comment: @wasthishelpful Oh, you're completely right. Well when it didn't show an error I thought "Yeah, that makes sense because I'm in the class". Weird.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you can't:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    void nonStaticMembFunc1(){};
    void nonStaticMembFunc2()
    {
         void (MyStruct::*funcPtr)() = &MyStruct::nonStaticMembFunc1;   // Declare local pointer

         (*funcPtr)(); // See error message below

    }
};
```

---

```
main.cpp: In member function 'void MyStruct::nonStaticMembFunc2()':
main.cpp:9:12: error: invalid use of unary '*' on pointer to member
          (*funcPtr)();   // Use it through this instance
            ^~~~~~~
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f62e19bc70050ef)

---

It's a member function pointer call. This appears separated from the current instances context, hence `this` isn't implicit there.

Comment: Right, but when you go (*funcPtr)() , the actual operator to call the nonstatic member function isn't there, it's supposed to be -> * if called through a pointer to the object, or .* if called on the object itself.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice I updated my answer with an explanation why `this` isn't (and cannot be) assumed _implicit_ for this case.